# React Monaco-Editor typescript Integration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, monaco-editor

According to the docs of @monaco-editor/react we need the original monaco-editor as a peer dependency. I installed that as a dev dependency and tried to add `node_modules/monaco-editor/monaco.d.ts` to the `include` block in my `tsconfig.json`. But I am still not able to access the type declarations after this. the only way I could get it to work was to import it like this.

`import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';`

but now my type declarations are throwing error when I try to define them for `editor` and `monaco` variables. Does anybody know hot get these working ?

here's my code when trying to define the types.

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import Editor from '@monaco-editor/react';
import styles from '../Code.module.css';
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';
type Language = {
  languageName: string;
  languageID: number;
};

type EditorProps = {
  language: Language;
  onCodeChange: Function;
};
type Monaco = typeof monaco // to use it as a type for the monaco variable in handleEditorDidMount function

const CodeEditor = ({ language, onCodeChange }: EditorProps) => {
  console.log('language is ', language);

  const [editorValue, setEditorValue] = useState('//some comment');

  const editorRef = useRef(null);

  const monacoRef = useRef(null);

  const handleEditorDidMount = (editor: monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor, monaco: Monaco) => {
    editorRef.current = editor;
    monacoRef.current = monaco;
    
    console.log(monaco.languages.getLanguages());
    console.log('editor', editor.getModel().getLanguageIdentifier().language);
  };

  const handleEditorValueChange = (value: string|undefined) => {
    //console.log('event is ', event);
    setEditorValue(value);
  };
  const editorOptions: monaco.editor.IStandaloneEditorConstructionOptions = {
    fontSize: 15,
    minimap: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  };
  return (
    <div className={styles.editorBlock}>
      <div className={styles.editorNav}>
        <button>Submit</button>
        <button>Change Language</button>
      </div>
      <Editor
        height="90vh"
        language={language.languageName}
        defaultValue={editorValue}
        onMount={handleEditorDidMount}
        onChange={handleEditorValueChange}
        options={editorOptions}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

In my `handleEditorDidMount` function, the argument monaco throws the error, cant use import as a type

Answer (score 0):

You make a number of wrong assumptions in your code.

1. Importing a typings file like a normal module won't make the typings available in your IDE.
2. Monaco has named exports, so use something like: `import { languages, editor } from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api";`. This imports the two namespaces `languages` and `editor`.
3. The module react-monaco exports `MonacoEditor`, not `Editor`.
4. `monaco` (as you imported it) is just the exports object from the monaco module. What do you expect form "typeof monaco"? Makes no sense.
5. What is the reference to `monaco` supposed to contain? A reference in React holds a pointer to an object, something that either was instantiated in the DOM or is the instance of a React component. Make no sense to have that ref for the monaco export.
6. A ref is usually initialised automatically in the render call, like:

```js
                <MonacoEditor
                    ref={this.editorRef}
                    language={language}
                    options={opts}
                />
```

so you don't need the mount function to set that.

Comment: Umm Let me go point by point

1. I really had no idea what I was doing but somebody in a github issue suggested doing that in tsconfig.

2. I'll try this out thanks

3,5 I think you need to go through the docs again, quite a lot of it has changed in `v4` of the package. I had picked it all up from the docs. As for ref to monaco aka `monacoRef`. I was just trying to find what `monaco` maps to in the official `monaco-editor` repo

4 I was actually looking through the `types.d.ts` in monaco-editor-react repo. That was how he defines them for his wrappings

Comment: Also for point 2. For me its a personal preference doing it like this plus this matches with the api docs themselves so its less confusing for me. I'm a beginner with typescript if that's not abundantly apparent

Comment: No worries, we all started as beginner in most fields. See if my hints may solve your problems.

Comment: it did work the way I'm defining types just some hiccups along the way